# Make NSTableView row editable when adding object with NSArrayController

Tags: interface-builder, nsuserdefaults, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have a table column of NSTableView bound to to an NSArrayController in Interface Builder.  The array controller is bound to `Shared User Defaults Controller` for the `Content Array`.  I had to select `Handles Content As Compound Value` to make adding new objects work.  Unfortunately, this disables the highlighting of the table row when I `add:` an object to the array.  The object is added but the table row is not highlighted and you have to double-click where you think the row is to be able to edit it.

My goal is to `add:` a row to the table view using the array controller; then, have that row automatically be highlighted and editable for the user.

Attributes for the NSArrayController:

[image]

Bindings for the the NSArrayController:

[image]

Bindings for the TableView Column:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I found [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Dec/msg00326.html) worked for me.

You need to subclass NSArrayController and implement your own add: method

```
//
//  MyArrayController.h
//

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface MyArrayController : NSArrayController

@end
```

and

```
//
//  MyArrayController.m
//

#import "MyArrayController.h"

@implementation MyArrayController


- (void)add:(id)sender {
    [super add:sender] ;

    [self performSelector:@selector(selectLastObject)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:0.0] ;
}

- (void)selectLastObject {
    if ([self selectsInsertedObjects]) {
        NSArray* arrangedObjects = [self arrangedObjects] ;
        NSInteger nObjects = [arrangedObjects count] ;
        if (nObjects > 0) {
            [self setSelectionIndex:nObjects-1] ;
        }
    }
}


@end
```